# Mockito: how to expect an iterator to be equal?

Tags: java, iterator, mockito

I have a method, which accept a string and an iterator:

```
public int doSomething(String str, Iterator<String> itr)
```

I am trying to mock a class, where this method is, so it would return me integer, depending on passed arguments. How can I call Mockito's `when()` so it expects passed iterator to be "equal" to the one I specify? As the passed iterator is build somewhere dynamically in system, I cannot use the same instance of it in `when()`, so I can only make a copy of it as my expectation:

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
aList.add("one");
aList.add("two");

MyClass myMock = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
```

I have tried following, and none of them seems to work:

```
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething("some string", aList.iterator())).thenReturn(10);
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(Matchers.eq("some string"), Matchers.eq(aList.iterator()))).thenReturn(10);
```

I only succeeded with using `anyObject()`:

```
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(Matchers.eq("some string"), Matchers.anyObject())).thenReturn(10);
```

but then of course I cannot set different results, depending on what is in iterator...

Comment: Could you provide sample code which you want make to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
when(myMock.doSomething(eq("some string"), argThat(new IsIteratorOfList(aList))))
```

where `IsIteratorOfList` is a subclass of [ArgumentMatcher](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) which checks that when the given iterator'selements are all added to a new list, this new list equals the list passed in the constructor (`aList` in this case).

The matcher could be even simpler and just check the first element, or the number of elements, or anything you want.

Comment: this works well, but only for case when there is only single matcher on a mock (this I unfortunately didn't mention in my question): if you have two or more matchers and, for example, first matcher runs iterator being tested through and finds it does not match - any further matcher would receive already "used" iterator, which cannot be run through again, so they all could not test it anymore and this would be wrong...

Comment: Yes indeed. Consider refactoring the code and tak a Collection as argument rather than an Iterator.

Comment: Hi just a readability tip, write your code as `when(myMock.doSomething(eq("some string"), isIteratorOf(aList)))` and somewhere in your test or in some DIY test util class wite a mehtod like `Iterator isIteratorOf(List list) { return argThat(new IsIteratorOfList(list)); }`. Plus I agree with @JBNizet, if you don't really need to consume an iterator, you should definately consider to refactor in order to accept an `Iterable` instead.

Comment: Not sure why you'd have two matchers running across the same iterator.  Is that in a single `verify` with two matcher arguments?  Or do you have successive calls to `verify`?  If it's the latter, I'd consider breaking your test case down into two separate test cases, with one `verify` in each.  If you can't do this, or if it's a single verify call, you might want to write a matcher that caches those Iterators for which it returns true.  Such a matcher would return true if EITHER the Iterator returns the correct elements OR it's an Iterator for which the matcher has already returned true.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented an `IterableMatcher<T>`.  This includes a static method `elemEq` that will create one of these for you.

For example:

```
doReturn(result).when(mock).method(elemEq(expected));
```

https://gist.github.com/collinsauve/1fcf924cdcced40e0bee

Answer (score 0):

You always could make your own implementation of the `Iterator` interface.